# Is the function mapping a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space to the maximum of its spectrum differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space. Is $$\left\{A\in\mathfrak L(H):A\text{ is self-adjoint}\right\}\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;A\mapsto\max\sigma(A)\tag1$$ differentiable? We know that this is true in the finite-dimensional case $H=\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$. If the claim as stated is not true in general, is there at least a similar result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $A(t) = \pmatrix{ t & 0 \\ 0 & -t}$. 
Then
$$
\max \sigma (A(t)) = |t|,
$$
which seems not to be differentiable at zero.

Comment: But it is Lipschitz and hence at least differentiable in a weak sense.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping is Lipschitz and from
$$\max \sigma(A) = \sup\{(x,Ax) \;|\; \|x\| \le 1\}$$
it should follow that it is convex (as a supremum of linear functions (w.r.t. $A$)). Hence, it should be subdifferentiable and directionally differentiable.

Comment: At least the numerical range $\left\{\langle Ax,x\rangle_H:\left\|x\right\|_H=1\right\}$ is convex (and bounded).

Comment: I need to think about it, but what would you say that we can say about the derivative? Can we give an explicit form?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, there is an explicit formula: The derivative in direction $H$ is given by $\sup \{x^\top H x \;|\; x \text{ is an eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue of } A\}$. In the infinite-dimensional case, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This question might yield the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3387919/47771. Do you've got an idea?